# How do i convert a number to a month in Go

Tags: go

I just want to take an integer input and convert it into corresponding month using Go time package. Is there a way apart from defining months in using a const block and using iota to incrementally represent them ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the type `time.Month`, which implements the `Stringer` interface, which means you can do something like:

```
m := time.Month(10)
fmt.Println(m) //"October" - could also do m.String() here
fmt.Println(int(m)) //10
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PeFfVZZIK_

Comment: [Official go docs for time.Month](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Month)

Comment: How would you do the reverse? (month to number) @dave

Comment: Just create a `map[string]int` and populate it with your month names.  `var longMonthNames = map[string]int{
 "January": 1,
 "February": 2,
 "March": 3,
 "April": 4,
 "May": 5,
 "June": 6,
 "July": 7,
 "August": 8,
 "September": 9,
 "October": 10,
 "November": 11,
 "December": 12,
}
`